# How to design schema for lots of different database flags

Tags: database, database-design

I have a table that has the potential to have a lot of different flags. What is the best way to handle this?

Here are the options I came up with

1. Multiple Many-to-many table with some flags left in the main table
2. One Generic many-to-many table called TableAttributes or flags that is used for all the table flags. More of the handling is left in the code
3. Everything as a flag in the table itself (leads to giant tables)

Other ideas???

Comment: Personally I would lean towards option #1 (except with *none* of the flags left in the main table) if the total number of tables requiring these flags is small (like under 10).  Any more than that, and I would go for option #2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two questions:

- Are the flags *predetermined*?
- Do you need to *search* on them?

Assuming flags are **not** predetermined, you'll need something like this:

[image]

The flag is "set" for the given item if the corresponding row is present in the `FLAG` table and "reset" if the row is absent. If you need to distinguish between "NULL" and "reset", you can add `FLAG_VALUE` field.

This structure answers the following question efficiently: **"Given an item, which flags does it have?"**. If this is all you need, you can avoid secondary indexes and make the table [clustered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-organized-clustered-index) (aka. "index-organized" in Oracle).

On the other hand, if you also want to (efficiently) answer the question: **"Given a flag, which items have it set?"**, you should add an index on `{FLAG_NAME}`, or possibly a [covering index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossary/covering-index) on `{FLAG_NAME, ITEM_ID}`.

---

If all the flags **are** predetermined, simply represent each flag as a separate column. Index those that you need to search on, possibly using a bitmap index if your database supports it, and modification performance requirements allow it.

You can use a bitmap to pack the flags more tightly on databases that don't represent Boolean values efficiently (such as Oracle) and potentially use [function-based indexes](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_function_based_indexes.htm).

Answer (score 1):

An approach I have used in the past is to leverage bitmaps. These can be modeled into the table as simple Integer or Big Integer columns. You then have the flexibility to change and enforce the flags used via code without having to change the database model.

For example, simple power of 2 values are your flags: 1, 2, 4, 8, and 16

```
select 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16
Result: 31
```

Your flag column would simply store the value 31 when all 5 flags are active. You can check if a flag is active with a bitand:

```
select 1 where 31 & 4 = 4
Result: 1
```

In this case, we know the flag for bit 4 is active. It is easy to work with bitmap in SQL code and of course in client application where bitwise math is an integral part of the language. The bitmap can be encoded in an enumeration and referenced easily in client code and store procedures with constants.

Comment: I've seen this approach and the thing I don't like about it is that it is hard to figure out the data in the table without running a bitwise style query

Comment: @chobo it is very easy to overlay the table with a view that normalizes the bitmaps into columns, but few people besides the DBA that created it are looking at the raw table data.

Comment: So you said to model them as integers and then check the flags using bitwise math in the code. Wouldn't this mean that you have to load larger datasets into memory and then filter them down? Seems inefficient. I like the bitwise approach for something like this, but I think a better question would be whether or not there's a database that supports bitwise math natively

Comment: And it appears that TSQL just might! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

I wonder how well it performs...